# Верстка DataGrid В XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

Как реализовать таблицу такого вида на XAML? Туплю конкретно. Если не сложно, можно готовый код или ссылку на статью, где подобное подробно описывается
[image: Таблица]

Comment: Проще отказаться от DataGrid вовсе

Comment: вам нужно просто получить такую таблицу или для определенных данных построить?

Comment: Какой функционал потом требуется от этой таблицы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

именно с помощью `DataGrid` такое очень сложно сделать, проще без и зависит от того, как вам надо:
1) просто, статично (почти навсегда) -- на `Grid` вручную набросать по линеечкам пропорциональные( * ) клеточки, в которых поместить различные `Label` с требуемым оформлением и содержимым;
2)сложно, с возможностью динамического генерируемого содержимого -- например:
в горизонтальный `StackPanel` вложить несколько вертикальных `DockPanel`(для групп "Понед.-Пятн.", "Субб.", "Сокр. день") с построчным наполнением элементами на основе тех же `Label`, каждую пару/квартет (для отдельной строчки) которых уместить в `Grid` с пропорциональными( * ) колонками/столбцами.

Comment: не уверен что понимаю почему такое сложно сделать с `DataGrid`

Comment: @FoggyFinder  говорю только за своё имхо) расскажите свой вариант общими словами, мне было б интересно.

Comment: HeaderRowTemplate + ColumnTemplate, но действительно если из всей работы только отобразить расписание то статично будет быстрее

Comment: @FoggyFinder  да, если не требуется повторить дизайн, но тут ещё междустрочные жёлтые линии, отступы между группами("Понед.-Пятн.", "Субб.", "Сокр. день") столбцов и, если меня глаза не обманывают, придётся поморочиться с оформлением -- тут местами разная толщина линий границы клеток/строк/столбцов, почему-то   :-/

Comment: вот с линиями, да, придется повозится. Как-то не могу сразу придумать как это нормально реализовать